# Handsontable get coordinates of cell in table

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I am currently trying to get the cell type when data is changed within handsontable. From what I am reading on their documentation there isnt a function for getting the column index of the cell changed or the columns datatype. In my afterChange function I am trying to see if the column is a date type column so I can format my dates to how my api wants to receive them can anyone give a step in the right direction? I have seen where you can loop though a column header and get the index but that will be extremely slow.

Comment: I'm looking for something similar to how the beforeOnCellMouseDown function allows you get the coordinates of the cell except on change because the on change only allows two parameters the change and the source.

Answer (score 0):

The afterChange() method takes a parameter 'e'. Logging it gives :

```
e: Array(2)
0:Array(1)
       0:Array(4)
              0 : (row)
              1 :  (column name)
              2 :  (old value)
              3 :  (new value).
```

If I am right, the column index can be found by the column name.